# How estimate or get the value of PDOP from HDOP value?

Tags: gps

I have a gps device that are reporting me the HDOP value and the number of satellites around, but I have as requirement to get the PDOP also, the GPS device doesn't give that value.
Can I get PDOP value from HDOP and the number of sats?

Comment: How are you accessing the values?  Are you using the NMEA stream or an API for the GPS?  If you're using NMEA, you can create an interpreter to pull PDOP values out of the string (assuming it is being reported).  I would be interested to see if there is a conversion out there somewhere though.

Comment: I'm getting the data using an API, I can't request a NMEA stream from the device.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get PDOP from HDOP. PDOP brings in a vertical dimension (VDOP) which is rarely made available separately.

Your options are:

- to calculate it yourself from the geometry at the time (i.e. if you know which satellites were in solution at any given time; and you know the resulting position; you could derive it).
- make some assumptions which are almost certainly bogus (like just multiplying by 1.4; which would be sort-of saying that all the satellites were all at medium elevation all the time).

In the end, if you don't have the data, you probably just have to accept that, or get the data you need.